# Android start activity shows error

Tags: android, android-activity, android-framelayout, android-phone-call

When i developing an android app. I want to call a number programatically. On using

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
```

It shows an error. I am using FrameLayout instead of Activity.

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1366)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1353)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:322)
at com.happiness.lockscreenlibrary.view.LockView$1.onDrag(LockView.java:163)
at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:18339)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1492)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1478)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1478)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5143)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$700(ViewRootImpl.java:108)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3331)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

I have used `context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(callIntent);` or  `context.startActivity(callIntent);` instead of `getContext().startActivity(callIntent);`
But it shows the same error . How it will solve please help me.

Comment: `Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.`

Answer (score 2):

To start activity from service, or whereever except another activity, you have to add flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the intent.

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
callIntent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add **setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)**

> If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this
>   history stack.

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(callIntent);
// use getActivity().startActivity(callIntent); if you are inside a fragment
```

You can get info about intent flags here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK If set, this activity will become the start of
>   a new task on this history stack.

Answer (score 1):

call your **startActivity** with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
logcat pointing the error and you still posting it on SO

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
callIntent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding flag to your intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Your code will be

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
```

Hope will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass context from activity to view using constructor.

```
new LockView(this);
```

use the same context to start a new activity.

```
   Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to start new activity.